# Restrict a custom plugin functionality to a specific Woocommerce product or category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

First of all, I understand there are similar topics on stackoverflow, but nothing that I have tried that should work, is working for me.

I have created a plugin to take text input from the user on all product pages. I need this extra functionality to only run on certain products, or certain products within a category.

Here is the functionality.

```
function kia_custom_option(){
$value = isset( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) : '';
printf( '<label>%s</label><input name="_custom_option" value="%s" />', __( 'Custom Text: ', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ), esc_attr( $value ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'kia_custom_option', 9 );

function kia_add_to_cart_validation($passed, $product_id, $qty){

if( isset( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) && sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) == '' ){
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '%s cannot be added to the cart until you enter your custom text.', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ), $product->get_title() ), 'error' );
    return false;
}

return $passed;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'kia_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3 );

function kia_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){

if( isset( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) ) {
    $cart_item['custom_option'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_option'] );
}

return $cart_item;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'kia_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );

function kia_get_cart_item_from_session( $cart_item, $values ) {

if ( isset( $values['custom_option'] ) ){
    $cart_item['custom_option'] = $values['custom_option'];
}

return $cart_item;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'kia_get_cart_item_from_session', 20, 2 );

function kia_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values ) {

if ( ! empty( $values['custom_option'] ) ) {
    woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'custom_option', $values['custom_option'] );           
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'kia_add_order_item_meta', 10, 2 );

function kia_get_item_data( $other_data, $cart_item ) {

if ( isset( $cart_item['custom_option'] ) ){

    $other_data[] = array(
        'name' => __( 'Origin Email', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'value' => sanitize_text_field( $cart_item['custom_option'] )
    );

}

return $other_data;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'kia_get_item_data', 10, 2 );
```

I am trying to only display the text box on certain products or categories. I have a product with the ID of 680.

I tried this at the top of my plugin.

```
if (is_single( '680' )) {
//All the above code here.
}
```

But that didn't work. I also tried by category, and had no luck with that either. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong or how I can apply these functions to only certain products?

Edit --- I came to the solution of:

```
function kia_custom_option(){
global $product;

$product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

if($product_id == 680 || $product_id == 687){
    $value = isset( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) : '';
    printf( '<label>%s</label><input name="_custom_option" value="%s" />', __( 'Custom Text: ', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ), esc_attr( $value ) );
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'kia_custom_option', 9 );
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update** *(It seems that you are using a version of WooCommerce before version 3)*

For product categories you can use [**`has_term()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) Wordpress conditional function with the corresponding `'product_cat'` custom taxonomy used by WooCommerce, just in your first hooked function, where you will define the allowed product category (or product categories) this way:

```
function kia_custom_option(){
    global $product;

    // HERE set your allowed product categories (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    $product_categories = array( 't-shirts', 'socks' );

    // Added WooCommerce retro compatibility
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    if( has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){

        $value = isset( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) : '';
        printf( '<label>%s</label><input name="_custom_option" value="%s" />', __( 'Custom Text: ', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ), esc_attr( $value ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'kia_custom_option', 9 );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works *(for all WC versions since 2.4)*. No need of anything else.

---

For defined **product Ids** the code will be:

```
function kia_custom_option(){
    global $product;

    // HERE set your allowed product IDs in the array
    $product_ids = array( 680, 687 );

    // Added WooCommerce retro compatibility
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    if( in_array( $product_id, $product_ids ) ){

        $value = isset( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) : '';
        printf( '<label>%s</label><input name="_custom_option" value="%s" />', __( 'Custom Text: ', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ), esc_attr( $value ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'kia_custom_option', 9 );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works *(for all WC versions since 2.4)*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Whilst I am sure this will work in my functions.php file, how can I enable this code to run from within my plugin? Putting this at the top of my plugin file, results in an error that causes the page not to display.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get it working within my plugin. I managed to get it working with an alternative solution, very similar to yours. I'll update the origin post with the solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @SamuelClayton Update: I think that the issue is due to the fact that you are using an old version of woocommerce (before version 3)… So I have added the compatibility. My code works now for all version of woocommerce since version 2.4 … So please, as this is working and answering your question, you should accept this answer and/or upvote~it if you want/like. Thanks